# Restart o reload HAProxy service

Tags: linux, http, haproxy

I am trying to restart using sudo `service haproxy restart` for the restart and `service haproxy reload` for the reload but it fails to do it, giving me this error:

```
Job for haproxy.service failed.
See "systemctl status haproxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow exactly what is suggested by a service error message, it will give you logs about the error. One more option you can try is to verify the configuration using the below command & take the necessary action.

```
haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```